# fit webapplication screen to iphone screen size ASP.NET

Tags: iphone, asp.net, html, ios5, ios4

I made a web application (ASP.NET Webforms) recently to be used as an IPhone hosted application.
I adjusted the body dimensions to : 768 width x 854 height, which is very commensurate to IPhone screen view, but bigger.
I've included the following in the header section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=1.5;"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="../logo.png" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

The thing is when you open this hosted application on IPhone, you have to zoom out in order to fit the web screen to the Iphone screen.
The question is: How may I get this automatically adjusted / scaled / zoomed out to the IPhone original dimensions?

Comment: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.41,user-scalable=1.5;"/>`